# Extract part of string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string (message) and its values change for each transaction. Here is the sample string:

"Your transaction was successful. Transaction ID: 453712046. Reference code: 1234326. Thank you!"

How can I extract the Transaction ID to a variable $transID and the Reference code to the variable $refCode as integer values every time a transaction is made?

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way, by using an API.

Comment: Just `explode()` with substring `Transaction ID: ` and then explode the ` ` second substring, the space. If the string is always consistent just use `explode`. Throwing regex at the problem is just using a BFG when all you need to do to keep the bugs out is close the door. ︎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily solved with a small bit of regex:

```
<?php

$str = "Your transaction was successful. Transaction ID: 453712046. Reference code: 1234326. Thank you!";
preg_match_all('#Reference code: (\d+)|Transaction ID: (\d+)#', $str, $matches);

$refCode = $matches[1][1];
$transID = $matches[2][0];

?>
```

[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all) performs a global regular expression match on the string. Meaning it won't stop after the first match.

`Reference code:` and `Transaction ID:` will match the literal strings.
`\d` Matches a digit ranging from 0-9.
`+` Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

So this means it will match any number after Reference code: and Reference code: for as long as it's not interupted by a non-digital character.

Comment: Will this work no matter how long the transaction ID or reference code is?

Comment: @bool Yes. For as long as the ID and Reference code consist of numbers only and aren't interupted by a space or any other character than a digit.

Comment: How can I make sure this code only extracts the transaction id and the reference code if the string had to contain other numerical values like time and date?

Comment: @bool You can't unless those numbers come _after_ the Reference code. In that case it won't matter as they will simply be ignored. If that's not an option, Mr Glass's answer to your question is a better solution for your problem.

Comment: @bool Technically you could count the position of the number though. `$matches[0]` will match the first number found. `$matches[1]` will match the second number found. `$matches[2]` the third etc etc. If you know how the string looks, the code is easily adepted to get the correct numbers.

Comment: here is the actual message (string) from which I need to extract the transaction id and reference code: "Yello.You have received ZMW 50.00 from Grace Namuchenje (260969754144) on your mobile money account at 2018-06-20 15:57:06. Reference code: 1234326. Your new balance:50.00 ZMW. Financial Transaction ID: 453712046.

Comment: @bool So simply count the numbers. The Reference code is the 10th number in the string and the Transaction ID is the 13th number. Change `$transID = $matches[12];` and `$refCode = $matches[9];`

Comment: @bool You can have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/mDhUfs/1 It gives you a clear representation of how it works.

Comment: Is there not a solution where I only extract digits between "Reference code: "  and ".", and between "Financial Transaction ID: " and "."

Comment: @bool I've edited my answer. It will now only match the numbers you want.

Comment: @bool If any of the answers to your question provided you with the answer you needed, please make sure to check the checkmark next to that answer to accept it. This is a way of showing your appreciation to the one that helped you out and makes sure your question doesn't remain open forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, and I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but this works:

```
$str = "Your transaction was successful. Transaction ID: 453712046. Reference code: 1234326. Thank you!" ;

// get the starting and ending of your first string
$pos1 = strpos($str,'Transaction ID: ') + strlen('Transaction ID: ');
$pos2 = strpos($str,'.',$pos1) ;

// get your transaction ID
$transID = substr($str,$pos1, $pos2-$pos1);

// get the starting and ending of your second string
$pos1 = strpos($str,'Reference code: ') + strlen('Reference code: ');
$pos2 = strpos($str,'.',$pos1) ;\

// get your reference code
$refCode = substr($str,$pos1, $pos2-$pos1);

echo $transID . ' - ' . $refCode ;
```

Comment: Will this work no matter how long the transaction ID or reference code is?

Comment: By reading his code, yes it will. Until the day the service you're collecting the data from changes their message.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option, you can do it with several ways.
This one is probably the easy to implement and understand, so also maintain.

```
$str = '"Your transaction was successful. Transaction ID: 453712046. Reference code: 1234326. Thank you!"';
$find = explode(" ",$str);
$Transaction_id = (int) $find[6];
$Reference_code = (int) $find[9];
echo $Transaction_id;
echo $Reference_code;
```

In order to work, the text must be the same and only change the numbers.
ie. 
    "Your transaction was not successful. Transaction ID: 453712046. Reference code: 1234326." wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex, named preferably to avoid confusion.

some pattern like

`/(?<first>Transaction ID: (?<transId>\w{1,})\.)(.*)(?<second>Reference code: (?<refCode>\w{1,})\.)/gm`

play arround on this: https://regex101.com/r/fO7ezY/1

```
<?php
    $re = '/(?<first>Transaction ID: (?<transId>\w{1,})\.)(.*)(?<second>Reference code: (?<refCode>\w{1,})\.)/m';
    $str = 'Your transaction was successful. Transaction ID: 453712046. Reference code: 1234326. Thank you!';

    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    // Print the entire match result
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```

If you are worried about the squence of the transaction ID and reference Code, you could match the pattern twice.